# Appending part of a tuple into a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I created a dictionary and I need to add the value of the single tuple into a new dictionary.I cannot seem to get my keys method to work. I get this error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

> This is where my key method is located. I get an error in the line that has 
>   newlist.append(i[0]). I am trying to append the key part of the tuple into a  > new list name *newlist*

```
def keys(self):
    newlist = self.flattened()
    keylist = []
    for i in newlist:
        newlist.append(i[0])
    return newlist
```

> This is my TestCase for the keys method

```
class test_keys(unittest.TestCase):
def test(self):
    s = Dictionary([[0, "zero"], [1, "one"], [2, "two"], [3, "three"]
    self.assertEqual(s.keys(), [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: There's [more code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Do you get any error in particular?

Comment: @Scott Hunter Yes, "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @AChampion Tried to make my code as clean a possible with a clear problem.

Comment: @luisruiz720 provide a [mcve], your code is not verifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating through a list, and changing it simultaneously.

Change

```
def keys(self):
    newlist = self.flattened()
    keylist = []
    for i in newlist:
        newlist.append(i[0])
    return newlist
```

for

```
def keys(self):
    newlist = self.flattened()
    keylist = []
    for i in newlist:
        keylist.append(i[0])
    return keylist
```